# Sign in to an account on startup in development environment

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-2

In ASP.Net Core, how can I sign in to an account on startup in development environment using Identity?

I tried to get the SignInManager in the Configure function through the ServiceProvider.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var signInManager = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
            signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync("user", "password", true, lockoutOnFailure: false).Wait();
        }
...
```

But dotnet crashes at the PasswordSignInAsync call.

Comment: Of course it crashes - there is no any request during app startup, nobody can receive auth cookies.

Comment: Yeah, okay. Is this not possible or is it possible to send this after startup somehow?

Comment: You should do it on first request. Or, on ANY anonymous request (in DEV environment). Create your middleware and enable it on dev only.

Comment: Or, better - rethink your app. If you tired to use it every day (need to login every time) then your users may also be tired. Maybe you need "better" "remember me" option?